# Salesforce partner community user license cost

Tags: userlicense

I am looking to get details on salesforce partner community user license cost. Also, is it possible to convert regular salesforce user license into partner user license or it needs to be done during renewal with SF? Thanks.

Comment: This information is mainly on the Salesforce website and would be something to talk to the Account Executive about.

Comment: It's not there on the website. I am just trying to get idea about the rates if anybody is aware. Appreciate any help based on your experience. Thanks.

Comment: Prices and potential discounts are not something the community can answer reliably, please consult your salesforce account executive. We can only say there's much lower in cost than full salesforce user licenses.

Answer (score 1):

The communities list pricing can be found here 
[Salesforce Communities Pricing](http://www.salesforce.com/communities/pricing/)

Changing licence types would have to be done with renewal I think but really that is something to discuss with the Account Executive as it may be possible part way through the term, but would require a contract change.

Comment: Thank you. Link provides pricing for using communities not the community user license.